# Toolbar personalizado no aparece en el layout androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, actionbar, androidx

He creado un `toolbar` personalizado para agregar a mis layouts pero este no aparece. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_semibold"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/guide_title"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:baselineAligned="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class guide extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context ctx;
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide);
        ctx = this;
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
        if(mToolbar != null){
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            mToolbar.bringToFront();
        }

    }
}
```

En el código anterior, si saco el `if(mToolbar != null)`  la linea `mToolbar.bringToFront()` me arroja un `null exception`, no así el `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`.

Y en los `style` he quitado el action bar

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Según mi teoría eso debería ser suficiente para visualizar mi `toolbar`, al menos en el v7 widget.

Y para finalizar... desde que API está soportado el `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he tenido que incluir el `XML` de mi `toolbar` dentro de mis actividades, no sé si es el camino correcto o la opción más elegante, pero al menos puedo decir que es funcional.

Dentro de mi actividad:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Luego, definir mi `toolbar` como tal en el `onCreate` de la respectiva actividad.

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Otra alternativa es habilitar el `ActionBar` en los styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

y luego cambiarlo por uno personalizado mediante programación.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar);
```

He de mencionar que esta ultima opción no me ha terminado de convencer, pero la dejo por si algún día alguien la llega a necesitar.